# How can I check which textbox is selected in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following html code:

```
...
// javascript function
if(the user press the user box) {
     // do some action
}
...
user: <input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
```

There are 2 input boxes. When the user presses either input, it will call a JavaScript function to do something. I also want do some action when the user does something in the user box. However, I don't know how to set up the condition.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: mention if you are happy with jquery, because it would be much easier than regular JS.

Comment: @RPM1984, if in the jquery, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do something like this:

```
<input type='text' id='user' name='user' onKeyDown="keyDown(this);" />
<input type='text' id='email' name='email' onKeyDown="keyDown(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function keyDown(element) {
   if (element.id == 'user') {
      // do something
   }
}
</script>
```

Note the use of **this** as an argument to the **keyDown** function, so you can have the one function handling both elements, but you can distinguish *which one* triggered the event.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery,

```
$("input[type='text']").keydown(function(){

   // common action 

   if(this.id=="user"){
       //do user box action
   }

   // common action 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely understand your question but you can use the focus or focusin event in jQuery.
This will run when your textbox gets focus.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
// code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe for the `onkeydown` event:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('user').onkeydown = function() {
        // the user pressed a key while inside the textbox => handle the event
        var value = this.value;
        // the value variable will contain the text entered in the textbox
    };
};
```

or if you use jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#user').keydown(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to track the events onKeyDown and onFocus. Just have these inserted in your `input` element and have them call the respective javascript function as shown below

```
<input type='text' id='user' name='user' onkeykown="function1();" onfocus="function2()">
```